# What is missing for the embedded Swagger to generate a x-www-form-urlencoded body?

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I am trying to find out why my Spring server generated by OpenAPI generator properly accepts requests with "user=foo", "password=bar" in a Postman POST request with x-www-form-urlencoded body (as expected), but the Swagger page embedded in the server using springfox-swagger2 generates a

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8080/v1.0/login?username=foo&password=bar' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -d ''
```

request, which returns a 415 Unsupported Media Type. For the record, the generated Java client from the OpenAPI specification shows the same behavior.  The generated Java method looks like:

```java
    @Operation(
        operationId = "loginPost",
        responses = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "User successfully logged in."),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "User login failed."),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "415", description = "Unsupported Media Type")
        }
    )
    @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        value = "/login",
        consumes = { "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
    )
    default ResponseEntity<Void> loginPost(
        @Parameter(name = "username", description = "", required = true) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "username", required = true) String username,
        @Parameter(name = "password", description = "", required = true) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "password", required = true) String password
    ) {
        return getDelegate().loginPost(username, password);
    }
```

(automatically generated, my code is in the getDelegate() delegate).

My guess is that the attributes on the generated Java code is slightly off, so I would like to find out what needs to be fixed so I can report a bug to the OpenAPI generator project, hopefully with a patch.

What is the reason for what I see?